# JavaFX 8 Dialog Button Area

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Please see this gist to see what I am trying to achieve: https://gist.github.com/d9e22915234e6ea34d20

The code is heavily cut down on the problem I face. As you can see when running the code there is a "miss" detected on the label or the text area (if you miss it by 5em or whatever). Unfortunately this does not work for the Dialog's own buttons OK and Cancel (Please run the code and you will see immediately what i am talking about). If you click near an FX-Node it should detect wheter you missed it or not.

Does anybody know if it is possible to detect clicks in the Dialogs button area?
And if it is possible, how to link them to the node like the label and the area?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? Your explanation isn't very clear.

Comment: If you run the code, and click besides the label or the textarea, there is a console print, telling you that you missed the said component. The same print should appear for OK and Cancel, but does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you're seeing, I would guess that the Dialog consumes click events in the button bar, so they don't make it to the Window (which is where you added the EventHandler). If you really want to do this, you can change `addEventHandler` to `addEventFilter`. This works for me.

Read this tutorial if you want to find out why this works:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm#CEGJAAFD